# how to connect ejabberd server to Logica opensmpp

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smpp, opensmpp

I am developing an application which uses the IM messages from Chat client and send it as a text message using SMPP client-server architecture. For XMPP I am using Ejabberd server and for SMPP I am using Logica opensmpp. My plans is when ejabberd server receives an IM message it should send the message and JID(as JID contains phone no of sender and receiver) to Logica opensmpp where I can convert it into a text message and send it to the customer. So my question is how can I connect Ejabberd server with Java application, which module of ejabberd server will be used in this scenario as I am new to Ejabberd server and If you think you have a better approach for above application or if there is any flaw please let me know 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an ejabberd Erlang plugin that will be doing HTTP / HTTPS ReST calls to your Java backend. That's the most common approach for integrating ejabberd with a third-party backend.

Comment: Does mod_rest or mod_restful module will help in this scenario??

Comment: I do not think so, as it does the reverse of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more point to @Mickaël Rémond : (Add a queue in between) You can write a ejabberd plugin that will push incoming message to a queue and in Java backend you should have a consumer that will process the data and send message back to your customer using **mod_rest**.

So, what you basically need is a **Erlang producer** & **Java consumer** to process and send back message to target users.

You can explore [eKaf](https://github.com/helpshift/ekaf) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html) client for the same.